# Spark kafka streaming failing to determine position of partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

I am creating a Spark streaming application with Kafka.

```scala
val kafkaParams = Map[String,Object](
        ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG -> kafkaConfig.bootstrapServers,
        ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
        ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG -> "some_random_client",
        ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG -> kafkaConfig.offsetResetConfig,
        ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG -> (true: java.lang.Boolean),
        ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG -> "120000",
        ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG -> "120000"
      )

val dStream: DStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String](ssc,
        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
        Subscribe[String, String](Array(kafkaConfig.topic), kafkaParams))

dStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        // COMPUTE
      })
```

Unfortunately it's failing to start as it fails to determine `position` of a specific `partition`. I see the following driver log - `expired before the position for partition <topic_name>-1 could be determined`.

Here is the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` output:

```
TOPIC               PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                      HOST            CLIENT-ID
topic_name 1          2244            2586            342             consumer-81-6f05cb98-2443-4301-b70f-d06a9385bfdc /10.66.242.213  consumer-81
topic_name 2          2506            2834            328             consumer-81-6f05cb98-2443-4301-b70f-d06a9385bfdc /10.66.242.213  consumer-81
topic_name 0          2695            3048            353             consumer-81-6f05cb98-2443-4301-b70f-d06a9385bfdc /10.66.242.213  consumer-81
topic_name 4          2587            2944            357             consumer-81-6f05cb98-2443-4301-b70f-d06a9385bfdc /10.66.242.213  consumer-81
topic_name 3          2249            2578            329             consumer-81-6f05cb98-2443-4301-b70f-d06a9385bfdc /10.66.242.213  consumer-81
```

I am able to consume messages from the above topic using the `kafka-console-consumer.sh`

Comment: Can you share full stacktrace?

Comment: hi @mazaneicha the issue has resolved on it's own, which makes me think that probably it had something to do with the Kafka Broker. Unfortunately can't reproduce it any more.